# Recycle a project name?

Tags: open-source, project, naming

I want to start an open source project, but my favourite project name was already used for a framework with the same goal. This project was never popular, there is nothing to download or executable, the project had only two active days with commits at Google Code and is dead since four years. In other words: the project is irrelevant but the name is in use at Google Code and ohloh (the same dead project). The .org domain would be available.

Would it be ok to reuse this project name?

Comment: Why not simply contact the project owner(s) and ask them?

Comment: I tried that, but it is not possible to contact them.

Comment: Have you tried talking to Google Code people? What is the policy on the projects at GC?

Comment: @Konrad, projects in Google Code remain there forever... even if you delete them.

Comment: Google has not defined a maximum time of inactivity, but there might be a chance to takeover the project: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#What_should_I_do_if_I_wish_to_take_over_a_project_that_appears_a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 years, just 2 active days? Get it and make it better then old dead one ;)

Comment: In the end decided to use another, better, name. But if I hadn't fount a better name, I had recycled the name.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against it, even if it is clearly dead. Recycling old names can cause a great deal of confusion. Moreover, if the old project has been indexed, then searches for your project or for documentation for your project could accidentally turn up information related to the previous project. There are plenty of good names out there that haven't been taken. Better to brainstorm now than cause confusion later.

Comment: The project is practically absent in search engines.

Comment: What would you say, if I could takeover the Google Code project?

Comment: @deamon, if they haven't released any downloads, then go ahead, but if they have a download, then I'd say choose a different name just to avoid any confusion.